# Querying derived table in Entity Framework + using aggregates

Tags: sql, entity-framework, aggregate, derived

I do not even know where to start with this.

How do I query a derived table in Entity Framework?

Here is a SQL query I want to translate to Entity:

```sql
SELECT
    count(question_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        question_id 
    FROM
        user_answers
    WHERE
        user_id = 'xyz'
        AND
        correct = 1
    GROUP BY
        QUESTION_ID
    HAVING
        count(*) > 1
) as b
```

Can anybody provide any insight into this?

Many thanks!

Kevin

Comment: `Int32 count = await dbContext.UserAnswers.Where( ua => ua.UserId == "xyz" && ua.IsCorrect ).Select( ua => ua.QuestionId ).Distinct().CountAsync();`

Comment: Can you show your user_answers model ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it pointed me in the right direction. I achieved it by writing this: `dbContext.UserAnswers.Where(x => x.UserId == "xyz" && x.Correct == 1).GroupBy(c => c.QuestionId).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 2).CountAsync();`